# A question about adding a vector compare instruction backend in GCC

Tags: c++

Recently,I am trying to add vector compare instruction in GCC backend. For example:
a c code like this:

```
typedef int  vsb64 __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (64), __may_alias__));
vhb64 x, y, z;
z = x == y;
```

I want to translate this code to my own instruction:

```
vcmpeq v1,v2,v3;
```

After I add a compare instruction pattern in the md file. It turns out that GCC can not recognize it. It translate this c code into a combination of a lot of scalar instructions. This is not what I want.
And also, I found the gimple tree:

```
z = VEC_COND_EXPR <x == y, { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                             -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                             -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                             -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
                           { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }>;
```

I find gimple tree extract my vector into many scalar.
Pleas, Can anyone help me with this? I feel so painful in this problem. Thanks you !

Comment: It turns out that gimple tree is correct. But the gimple lowering is not result I want.  Because I saw gimple transform a lot short data in the lowering.